# Vectorize sum of outer products in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

Any ideas how to vectorize this code? The result S should be 3x3.

```
%PNorm is n x 3
S = zeros(3,3,n);
%TODO vectorize
for i = 1:n
    S(:,:,i) = Pnorm(i,:)'*Pnorm(i,:);
end
S = sum(S, 3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason not to do:

```
S = Pnorm' * Pnorm;
```

Hmm?

Comment: See, this is why I really need to take a linear algebra course :)

Answer (score 0):

For explicit computation you can trade the loop for `bsxfun`:

```
S = bsxfun( @times, permute( Pnorm, [2 3 1]), permute( Pnorm, [3 2 1] ) );
S = sum( S, 3 );
```

However, for an efficient computation see [EitanT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16140161/1714410)'s answer.